# How to reinitialize cart/quote after a checkout?

Tags: checkout, cart, session, quote

When a user checks out, the `quote` is becoming null, and the ID becomes 0.

This is causing a problem because the next time I'm calling

`cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')`;

and using the `cart` object to add a product to the cart, it's not saving after I call
`cart->save()`. What's weird is, the second time that I call the url to add the cart, it actually saves correctly. How can I properly initialize the cart if the quote is null so that it saves properly from the first time I try to add a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried init?

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
```

Comment: I have, yes. It had no effect..

Comment: Seems to work. I had to clean previous carts for that to work. Thank you.

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save()`
work for me :)